# Append in jsonb array and update existing record based on a key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have a table **media** with a jsonb array field **pictures** that contains an empty array.

The idea is that every time I append a new json object, I want to switch the default attribute from any previous one from true to false.

Sample object:

```
{"file": "file.jpg", "default": true}
```

I accomplished that with 2 different queries.

One for inserting a new record:

```
update media
set pictures = jsonb_set(
    pictures,
    concat('{' , jsonb_array_length(pictures) , '}')::text[],
    jsonb_build_object('file', 'somepicture.jpg', 'default', true)
)
where user_id = 8
```

And one for switching from **default: true** to **default:false**

```
update media
set pictures =
(
    select
        jsonb_agg(
            case when value->>'default' = 'true' and value->>'file' != 'somepicture.jpg'
            then value || jsonb_build_object('default', false)
            else value
            end
        )
    from jsonb_array_elements(media.pictures)
)
where user_id = 8
```

My final pictures array:

```
[
 {
  "file": "previouspicture.jpg",
  "default": false
 },
 {
  "file": "somepicture.jpg",
  "default": true
 }
]
```

How can I achieve the same thing, with only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an extra `jsonb_set()` to update the previous object. You have to use `coalesce()` to be able to start with an empty array:

```
update media
set pictures = jsonb_set(
    coalesce(
        jsonb_set(
            pictures,
            array[(jsonb_array_length(pictures)-1)::text],
            pictures->jsonb_array_length(pictures)-1 || '{"default": false}'
            ), 
        pictures
    ),
    array[(jsonb_array_length(pictures))::text],
    jsonb_build_object('file', 'filename.jpg', 'default', true)
)
where user_id = 8
returning *;
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e7acb4682d3956b89eacecfdca7a8f01)